# Is it possible to convert array filed to rows using MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The source data is like following:

[
{
_id:'***',
info:'***',
data:[
{
_id:1,
title:***,
created:***
},
{
_id:2,
title:***,
created:***
}
]
}
]

I want to manipulate the final result like following using MongoDB aggregation framework:

```
[
    {
        _id:1,
        title:***,
        created:***
    },
    {
        _id:2,
        title:***,
        created:***
    }
]
```

Comment: So you mean you don't want _id:"info" field only data array ?

Comment: Yes. I don't want root _id and info fields.

Comment: I have added aggregate in answer, accept if thats what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what you should do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$data"
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$data"
        }
     }
])
```

See live example here:
[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fY6gXgcfdsm)